# Determine the set for $z \in \mathbb{C} : \sqrt[n]{|5\cdot(-1)^n\cdot z + 3z|^n} < 1$

Tags: analysis, complex-numbers

> Determine the set for $z \in \mathbb{C} : \sqrt[n]{|5\cdot(-1)^n\cdot z + 3z|^n} < 1$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ is non-zero.

**What I've got so far:** $\sqrt[n]{|(5\cdot(-1)^n\cdot z + 3z)|^n} = |5\cdot(-1)^n\cdot z + 3z|  = |5\cdot(-1)^n\cdot + 3|\cdot|z|$

Now with the triangle inequality we get

$$|5\cdot(-1)^n\cdot  + 3|\cdot |z| \le (|5\cdot(-1)^n | + |3|)\cdot |z| = 8\cdot |z|$$

$$8\cdot|z| <^! 1 \Longleftrightarrow |z| < \frac{1}{8}$$

Now, I'm especially unsure if it is allowed to do the part with the inequality or if I went in a wrong direction. If you have any objections or can confirm that one can do it like this I would be thankful!

Comment: If $|5(-1)^n+3|$ is strictly smaller than $8$, you will be excluding lots of possibilities for $z$. Why not simply look at the cases when $n$ is even or odd separately?

Comment: $\sqrt[n]{|w|^n}=|w|$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews I did just that

Comment: I don't see where $|5(-1)^n+3|$ is strictly smaller than $8$. It is smaller than $8\cdot |z|$, a range of $-\infty$ to$ +\infty$.